# Como usar corretamente o Discod EMBED bot

Tags: node.js

Como é possível formatar a mensagem que o bot envia desse jeito? eu até consigo fazer, porem não consigo colocar divisões na mesma linha, e se possível tem como colocar background na divisão?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qual é a library que está a utilizar?
Se estiver a utilizar o `discord.js` deverá utilizar: `.addField("nome", "valor", true)`.
O último argumento é se deverá mostrar o campo na mesma linha.

Answer (score 0):

Use o `Rich.Embed()` para criar as embeds
Você pode criar uma let para setar todas as Field como inline
`let inline = <true>`
`.addFiled("<nome">", "valor", inline)`

Answer (score -1):

Se estive usando a versão **12** do discord.js use `Message.Embed()` para criar as embeds.
Para fazer a divisão em linha adicione a inline como: **true**.